# Check convergence and sum of a sum of finite sum.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification, summation

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^m \left(\frac{x_k}{y}\right)^n\quad 0<x_k<y$$

---

My attempt:

Convergence:

Since $\frac{x_k}{y} <1$ we can conclude that:

$$\sum_{k=1}^m \left(\frac{x_k}{y}\right)^{n+1}<\sum_{k=1}^m \left(\frac{x_k}{y}\right)^n$$

So $a_n = \sum\limits_{k=1}^m \left(\frac{x_k}{y}\right)^n$ is positive and decreasing and bounded by $0$ and $\sum_{k=1}^m \left(\frac{x_k}{y}\right)$ so by monotone converge theorem the overall sum converges.

The sum is found by recognizing hat we have a sum of a sum of geometric series (plural).

So we have:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^m \left(\frac{x_k}{y}\right)^n = \frac{1}{1-\frac{x_1}{y}} + \frac{1}{1-\frac{x_2}{y}} + \frac{1}{1-\frac{x_3}{y}}  + \dots+ \frac{1}{1-\frac{x_m}{y}}$$

Does this make sense and can the sum be simplified further?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sum convergence analysis is incorrect: $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{i}$ is divergent but $\frac{1}{i}$ is positive and decreases to 0.

You can prove it this way: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{x_k}{y}\right)^n$ converges (as it's just a geometric series - this part you got right); then use the fact that if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges to $A$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$ converges to $B$, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n+b_n$ converges to $A+B$ (there is a similar theorem for limits: [theorem + proof](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Combination_Theorem_for_Sequences/Sum_Rule)).